# Invalid column name: "ColumnName#" with a suffix number

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table `Users`:

[image]

I am using Entity Framework 6 to make the type configuration

```
public class UsersMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Users>
{
    public UsersMapping()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.UserID);
        Property(t => t.UserID).IsRequired();

        ToTable("Users", "dbo");

        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("UserID");
    }
}
```

and this is the `Users` class:

```
public class Users : EntityBase
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateActivated { get; set; }
    public bool LockedOut { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int? State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string SecurityQuestion { get; set; }
    public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? ReportServiceAccount { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int? ILAC { get; set; }
    public string BioFingerprint { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Squad { get; set; }
    public byte[] SignatureFile { get; set; }
    public byte? CETGroupID { get; set; }
    public string TokenID { get; set; }
    public int? Pin { get; set; }
    public string RadioNr { get; set; }
}

public class EntityBase
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to set the Id field as primary because my repository pattern works using the field Id that is not present on this case in the table. But when I am trying to get the set of users I get this error:

> The column name is invalid UserID1

The weird thing to me is the #1 that is at the end. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the `UserId` property and related mapping. This way the property `Id` will be mapped to the `UserId` column.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, that solved the problem, but is no there a way to keep the UserID as part of the model as I intended and still having it working?

Comment: use Property(t => t.UserID).HasColumnName(NewName); the resulting table must not have two columns with the same name, so it chose the name "UserID1". If there is no other column, choose the .Ignore function instead.

Comment: It's possible to make `UserID` property delegating it's get/set to `Id` and making it unmapped (by using `Ignore` method), but IMO it would just create problems - first, it's strange to have 2 properties representing one and the same thing, and second, you should remember not using `UserID` property in LINQ to Entities queries because you'll get runtime exceptions.